# Can I save drafts in the iOS Messages app

Tags: ios, messages

I don’t see any functionality to compose a Message and save it as a draft on iOS.

Is this possible using the messages app on iOS 17?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no draft option. But If you type any text in a inbox and don't send it stays there.